# Navigation from a destination to another destination in another navigation graph in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm new at navigation graph and I have a simple movie application that contains a `BottomNavigationView` with 2 tabs or 2 icons , the first icon or first tab contains 2 `Fragments` the first one is `FeedFragment` and I navigate from it to `DetailsFragment` and I put these 2 `Fragment` in `nested graph` . The second tab for `FavoritFragment` .

Below my code in `nav_graph.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeNavigation">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favoritesFragment"
        android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="@string/favorites"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favoritesFragment_to_homeNavigation"
            app:destination="@id/detailsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/homeNavigation"
        android:label="Home nested graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/feedFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/feedFragment"
            android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FeedFragment"
            android:label="@string/feed_page"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_feedFragment_to_detailsFragment"
                app:destination="@id/detailsFragment" />

        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
            android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.DetailsFragment"
            android:label="Details"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details">
            <argument
                android:name="movieItem"
                app:argType="com.tito.domain.entites.MovieModelItem" />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

I can navigate from `FeedFragment` to `DetailsFragment` and I pass a `Parcelable` object .
I want to navigate from `FavoriteFragment` to `DetailsFragment` (in the nested `navigationGraph`) and when I write the below code in `FavoriteFragment`

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            detailsViewModel.getSavedMovie().collectLatest { movies->
               if(movies.isNotEmpty()) {
                   favoritesAdapter = FavoritesAdapter(object : FavoritesAdapter.OnItemClick{
                       override fun onItemClick(movieModelItem: MovieModelItem) {

                           val id = FavoritesFragmentDirections.actionFavoritesFragmentToHomeNavigation(movieModelItem)

                            findNavController().navigate(id)
                       }
                   })
                   binding.movieRec.adapter = favoritesAdapter
                   favoritesAdapter.differ.submitList(movies)
               }else{
                   Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"No data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               }
            }
        }
```

And run the app , I can't run it I get the below error

```
e: D:\MovieApps\app\src\main\java\com\tito\movieapps\ui\fragments\FavoritesFragment.kt: (48, 105): Too many arguments for public final fun actionFavoritesFragmentToHomeNavigation(): NavDirections defined in com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FavoritesFragmentDirections.Companion
```

I can't fix this error so please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59196327/6576302

Comment: I already added the second navigation graph in the ``nav_graph.xml`` . And when I  make an action from Favorite to the Home graph , it navigate to the Home no the Details screen

Comment: try to not pass any data, and test that without "movieModelItem". And see what will happen.

Comment: I changed the action to make it navigate to the homeGraph and in navigated to the FeedFragment which is the start destination of the homeGrapgh , but I need to navigate to Favorite Fragment which is the the second destination in the homeGraph , and when I change the action and make the destination to FavoriteFragment, it needs to pass to it the argument which is in the FavoritFragment .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution , thanks to Chat OpenAI

If I want to navigate from a fragment to another destination in another `navigation graph` we should do the following

1- Navigate from the destination(`Favorite Fragment`) to the other navigation graph (`Home Navigation Graph`)

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favoritesFragment"
        android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="@string/favorites"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favoritesFragment_to_homeNavigation4"
            app:destination="@id/homeNavigation" />
```

Then we make an action from the start destination (FeedFragment) in the `Home Navigation Graph graph` to the `DetailsFragment`  like the code below

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeNavigation">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favoritesFragment"
        android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="@string/favorites"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favoritesFragment_to_homeNavigation4"
            app:destination="@id/homeNavigation" />
    </fragment>
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/homeNavigation"
        android:label="Home nested graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/feedFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/feedFragment"
            android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FeedFragment"
            android:label="@string/feed_page"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_feedFragment_to_detailsFragment"
                app:destination="@id/detailsFragment" />

        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
            android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.DetailsFragment"
            android:label="Details"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details">
            <argument
                android:name="movieItem"
                app:argType="com.tito.domain.entites.MovieModelItem" />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>

</navigation>
```

Then in the `FavoriteFragment` in `OnItemClick`

```
  val id  = FavoritesFragmentDirections.actionFavoritesFragmentToHomeNavigation4()
                               findNavController().navigate(id)
                               val args = DetailsFragmentArgs(movieModelItem)
                               findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_feedFragment_to_detailsFragment,args.toBundle())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of full code of your project, so, I just can suggest a trick (that is a non-standard and temporary solution).

Add an `Boolean` argument e.g. `shouldIGo` and an Nullable variable `movieItemData` into your `homeNavigation`. My trick goes like this, if someone entered into this `homeNavigation` with `ShouldIGo == true` (and of course in this case `movieItemData` must be Non-null and attached to the direction) then
automatically navigate to `DetailsFragment` with that extra data.

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/homeNavigation"
    android:label="Home nested graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/feedFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedFragment"
        android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FeedFragment"
        android:label="@string/feed_page"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_feedFragment_to_detailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailsFragment" />

        <argument <!-- this has been added -->
            android:name="movieItemData"
            app:argType="com.tito.domain.entites.MovieModelItem"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:nullable="true"/>
        <argument <!-- this has been added -->
            android:name="shouldIGo"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
        android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.DetailsFragment"
        android:label="Details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details">
        <argument
            android:name="movieItem"
            app:argType="com.tito.domain.entites.MovieModelItem" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And in home fragment of `homeNavigation`, i.e. `FeedFragment` check that if `shouldIGo` is true or not. if it was true then navigate to `detailsFragment`.

```
private FeedFragmentArgs args;

...

onCreate ... 

args = FeedFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments());

if (args.shouldIGo == true) {
//navigate to detailsFragment with movieItemData data.
}
```

Comment: What is the destination from the Favorite Fragment ? I made it HomeNavigation but it doesn't accept any params even  I added the 2 argument in FeedFragment . Or should I make the destination to FeedFragment ?

Comment: As you have defined it by `action_favoritesFragment_to_homeNavigation` the destination is home fragment of `homeNavigation`.

Comment: Do you know how to play with navgraph in android studio? every thing is in right side panel. arguments, directions, etc.

Comment: Yes I have added the 2 argument in FeedFragment and I have added an action  from FavoriteFragment to HomeNavigation like the below code


``<fragment
        android:id="@+id/favoritesFragment"
        android:name="com.tito.movieapps.ui.fragments.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="@string/favorites"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favoritesFragment_to_homeNavigation3"
            app:destination="@id/homeNavigation" />
    </fragment>``


But I can't add parameters in the action

Comment: Parameters that I have defined is for `homeNavigation`. If someone (A) want to enter in `homeNavigation` he (A) must show his boolean key to allow to enter. this is like a lock and key. lock is in destination always and key is in hand of who wants to enter.

Comment: So If you want to use my trick, and travel from `favorites` to `homeNavigation`, in codes (not in graph) you should pass that boolean.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and show me how the action will be in Favorite Fragment ?

Comment: What you commented in above is ok. nothing else is needed in NavGraph.

Comment: But it doesn't need an arguments when I use the action in FavoritFragment 

``val id = FavoritesFragmentDirections.actionFavoritesFragmentToHomeNavigation3()
                               findNavController().navigate(id)``

Comment: Android studio will help you if it needs any argument, in this case it needs. Add a dot at the end of `FavoritesFragmentDirections.actionFavoritesFragmentToHomeNavigation3()` and see what it needs?

Comment: I should pass the arguments in the action not after it , it will not accept params cause the destination is HomeNavigation not FeedFragment

Comment: In java, if there are two arguments then it should pass after parenthesis. But I am not sure,